# Fetching the controller's name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('MainController', function MainController() {})
app.controller('directiveCtrl', function directiveCtrl() {})


  .directive('controllerName', function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div>My controller name is: {{cName}}</div>',
      controller: 'directiveCtrl',
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
        var name;
        console.log("printing");
        name = elem.controller().constructor.name;
        $scope.cName = name;
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="app" class="container">
  <div id="target" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>Type1</div>
    <div controller-name></div>
  </div>
  ***************************************************
  <div id="target" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-controller="directiveCtrl">Type2
      <div controller-name></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>
</div>
```

Hello,here i am trying get the name of the controller by using directive

1. **Type 1**:
   Here directive `controller-name` is having one parent controller named `MainController` and it's own controller defined inside the directive with name `directiveCtrl`...but when i try to access the controller name i am getting the name as `MainController` not `directiveCtrl`...why???
2. **Type 2**:
   Here i am getting the value directiveCtrl as it is outside...
   Can anyone explain in detail please
   Thanks in advance

Comment: What would be use case for ever needing to do this in the first place?

Comment: Knowledge and timepass

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [`element.controller()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> **`controller(name)`** - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent. By default retrieves controller associated with
>   the ngController directive. If `name` is provided as camelCase
>   directive name, then the controller for this directive will be
>   retrieved (e.g. `'ngModel'`).

The function gets the parent controller defined with `ng-controller`. This is a normal behavior, as you defined in **Type 1**:

```
  <div ... ng-controller="MainController">
      ...
  </div>
```

And in **Type 2**:

```
  <div ...
    <div ng-controller="directiveCtrl"> 
        ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If name is provided as camelCase directive name, then the controller for this directive will be retrieved ...what if the name is not in camelCase